# How to define minimum number of points to be included in a hexagon with stat_summary_hex()?

Tags: r

I have been searching for days for an answer but I could not find anything to help me out.

I have a large dataset with points defining longitude and latitude and a value. I wanted to plot them on a map with hexagons. The code I used for it was this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(lon, lat, group = value))+
  geom_polygon(data = df.shp,aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),  fill = "grey", show.legend = FALSE)+
  stat_summary_hex(bins = 50, binwidth = 0.5, aes(z = value), fun = "mean", colour = "black")+
  xlim(-20,50)+
  ylim(24,72)+
  scale_fill_viridis(
    option = "A",
    breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4))
```

I used two files, the `df.shp` to create a background map and `df` with my point data. The result I get is this:

[image]

I like the way the map looks but it feels a bit too clustered. What I would like to do somehow is define a minimum threshold of points that have to be included in one of the hexagons to show a value and if that threshold is not met I would like the hexagon to not appear basically. Is there anyway this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can change `bins` argument.

See example below with fake data

```r
# Library
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)

# Fake data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000), z = rnorm(1000))

# Change bins = 5
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
  stat_summary_hex(bins = 5)
```

[image]

```r
# Change bins = 30
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
  stat_summary_hex(bins = 30)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ruam Pimentel. I have been playing around with ```bins``` but to be perfectly honest, I have no idea how it actually works. If I increase the number then the number of the hexagons increases and their size decreases. But this still des not give me what I want. I want to have a threshold of lets say 20 for example, so if less than 20 of my data points fall in one of the hexagons, that hexagon should not be mapped.

Comment: `bins` is there to indicate how many hexagons you want to see in x and y-axis. For want you want, you I would play with `bins` and `binwidth` at the same time. Read document for both [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.1/topics/stat_summary_hex).

Comment: Do you know what unit ```binwidth``` is, is it in degrees?